# ApacheCordova and ASP.NET Controller No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, apache-cordova

I want to access a WebService from an ApacheCordovaApp via Ajax.
The WebService is a simple MVC ASP NET Controller.
I added this line to the action that gives the response in the Controller:

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

But went my App try to access to the URL, I've got the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load **MyURL** No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

At the same time using POSTMAN, I see that the Header **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *'** is present on the response.

Why the request gives me this error if the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the response?

Comment: I know I can add this Header in the **Web.Config** file. But I don't want to allow globally acces from any Domain. I just want some actions to allow it.